# Is it possible to sell weapons?

Tags: watch-dogs

I've just started playing Watch_Dogs, and have accumulated some low-level weapons that I'd like to sell, however I've been to the Pawn Shop and Gun Dealer, and neither have the option to SELL, only BUY!  So I'm wondering if selling weapons is even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you cannot sell your weapons.

Sources: [Gamefaqs1](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704529-watch-dogs/69345111), [Gamefaqs2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704529-watch-dogs/69359859), [Linustechtips](http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/159093-watch-dogs-selling-items/)